# Show that the set $A = \left\{ x+ \frac{\sin kx}{1+k},k=0,1,2, \dots \right\}$ is a compact subset of $C[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that the set $A = \left\{ x+ \frac{\sin kx}{1+k},k=0,1,2, \dots \right\}$ is a compact subset of $C[0,1]$.

I first set up a sequence $\{ f_k: f_k=x+\frac{sinkx}{1+k} \}$. And $f_k$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. I want to prove the subsequence of $f_k$ converges on $C[0,1]$ with limit in it. But then how do you define an appropriate subsequence?

Comment: Which topology/metric are you using on $C[0,1]$? You also need that *every* sequence has a convergent subsequence. So for any sequence of natural numbers $\{k_1,k_2,\dots\}$ you need a subsequence $\{k_{i_1},k_{i_2},\dots\}$ so that $\{f_{k_i}\}$ is convergent in $C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $k$, let $g_k:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g_k(x)=x+\frac{\sin kx}{k+1}$. Then, $A$ can be rewrite as $A=\{g_k\}_{k\ge 0}$.

Now, for each $k$ we have $|g_k(x)|\le 1+\frac{1}{k+1}\le 1+1=2$. Thus, $A$ is equibounded.

On the other hand, $|g_k^\prime(x)|=|1+\frac{k\cos kx}{k+1}|\le 1+\frac{k}{k+1}\le 2$. Thus, for every $k$ we have $|\frac{g_k(x)-g_k(y)}{x-y}|\le 2$. Then, the family $A$ is equicontinous.

By Arzelá-Ascoli Theorem, every sequence of elements of $A$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Show that the $f_k$, except for $k=0$, are isolated points. Show that $f_0$ is the limit of the sequence of the $f_k$.